# Mysql stored procedure set/declare variable issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am working in Mysql and I would like to create a stored procedure to insert in database if user does not have more than 10 hours in table rental.

Here is my code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_rental(in user_idInsert INTEGER, in fields_idInsert INTEGER, in startDateTimeInsert DATETIME, in endDateTimeInsert DATETIME, in monthDate INTEGER, in yearDate INTEGER, in user_role INTEGER) 
BEGIN  
DECLARE user_totalHours FLOAT(23,19); 

SELECT Sum(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(endDateTimeInsert,startDateTimeInsert))/3600)  
INTO user_totalHours  
FROM `rental`  
WHERE MONTH(startDateTime)=monthDate  
AND YEAR(startDateTime)=yearDate  
AND user_id = user_idInsert; 

IF user_role=2 && user_totalHours<10 THEN  
        INSERT INTO rental(user_id, field_id ,startDateTime, endDateTime)  
        VALUES(user_idInsert, fields_idInsert, startDateTimeInsert, endDateTimeInsert); 
    ELSEIF user_role!=2 THEN  
        INSERT INTO rental(user_id, field_id, startDateTime, endDateTime)  
        VALUES(user_idInsert, fields_idInsert, startDateTimeInsert, endDateTimeInsert); 
END IF; 
END
```

I have also tried this :

```
SET @user_totalHours = SELECT Sum(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(endDateTimeInsert,startDateTimeInsert))/3600)  
FROM `rental`  
WHERE MONTH(startDateTime)=monthDate  
AND YEAR(startDateTime)=yearDate  
AND user_id = user_idInsert;
```

But variable `user_totalHours` is always `NULL`

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you try removing the @ before user_totalHours?

Comment: It do not work without @ before user_totalHours

Comment: Your queries seem wrong, it is INSERT INTO not SELECT INTO and use UPDATE before using SET if you are trying to update a row.

Comment: I want to store in variable : user_totalHours (float) and if this float is under 10, do INSERT INTO `rental`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, it was that if there is nothing in rental for a month like january, null is the value, so I've changed my else if statement :

```
   DECLARE user_totalHours FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0; 

SELECT Sum(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(endDateTime,startDateTime))/3600)  
INTO user_totalHours  
FROM `rental`  
WHERE MONTH(startDateTime)=monthDate  
AND YEAR(startDateTime)=yearDate  
AND user_id = user_idInsert; 

    IF (user_role!=2) THEN
            INSERT INTO rental(user_id, fields_id ,startDateTime, endDateTime)  
            VALUES(user_idInsert, fields_idInsert, startDateTimeInsert, endDateTimeInsert); 
    ELSEIF (user_totalHours<10 || user_totalHours IS NULL) THEN  
        INSERT INTO rental(user_id, fields_id, startDateTime, endDateTime)  
        VALUES(user_idInsert, fields_idInsert, startDateTimeInsert, endDateTimeInsert);
        ELSE SELECT user_totalHours;
    END IF;
```